# pyrocms user module non ajax login

Tags: codeigniter-2, pyrocms

I'm hacking (I know I know) the user module to allow us to use a third party data source for user data, rather than store data as profile feeds.

I'm in the users.php controller, looking at the login function.
I cannot for the life of me see where the user info is fetched when the login form is processed via an ajax call it seems.

Does anyone know the system well enough to guide me. All I'm after is a user ID after they login.. I'll also post this on the parent website.

Answer (score 0):

Not all together sure what the question is, but if the question is where is the log in data processed, it is on or around line 707 in the users.php controller in the Users module by the `_check_login()` method/callback. The data is processed by the Ion Auth method login. If the details are successful, the user is logged in.

To get the current user log in details in a controller, you can do something like:

```
if ( $this->current_user )
{
  // User is logged in do stuff like assign the id to a variable or somethin'
  $current_user_id = $this->current_user->id;
}
else
{
  // User is not logged in, do something else
}
```

If the question was how to get the user data in the views, you can use the user plugin tags:

```
{{ if user:logged_in }}

<p>Hello {{ user:first_name }} {{ user:last_name }}!</p>

{{ else }}

<p>You are not logged in, fool.</p>

{{ endif }}
```

By the way, if you are considering hacking any module, consider either using Events or cloning the module to one of the addons folders.

https://www.pyrocms.com/documentation/2.0/developers/developer-tools/events

Good luck.

Comment: Cheers for this. The line if ($this->current_user) isn't set when we login the first time. The form validates and then I can't see where the variable is set.. if I revisit the login page, it IS set.. but for the life of me I can't see where...

Comment: Which variable? The login logic happens in the Ion Auth lib and Ion Auth model in the Users module.